# Python Pandas get a value from the cell if two columns have a values

Tags: python, pandas

I am studying python and pandas and I am having trouble.

I have a dataframe and CSV like:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | syfgusj |
| A | 2 | adaddsfd |
| B | 1 | adsghfjgftrds |
| B | 2 | adergtw |
| C | 1 | adergtw |
| C | 2 | addfgftre |

I am trying to get the value from the "c" column that is near the values in columns "A" and "B":

I'm trying to do something like:

```
If df[(df['A'] == "A") & (df['B'] == "2")]:
        print *value from "C": adaddsfd*
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```py
 df[(df['A'] == "A") & (df['B'] == "2")]['C']
```

should do it.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Can you help me one more?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: I will try to explain. I have the same DF with cyryllic names in A and B column, and I can not change it. In my program I cannot use this cyryllic names, only Latin. I made a dictionary like the following: ```{"apple":"яблоко", "potato":"картошка"}```. Can I find an english word in this dictionary, take a cyryllic analogue and use it in code:  ```df[(df['A'] == "cyryllic word") & (df['B'] == "cyryllic word")]['C']```?

Comment: @NothingHappen I would recommend asking this as a separate question, instead of a comment.

Comment: @NothingHappen If you want to replace the cyryllic word with english word using the dictionary, you can use [df.A.map(sample_dict)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print a string you can do:

```
df.loc[df['A'].eq('A') & df['B'].eq('2')]['C'].item()
```

It will give you:

```
'adaddsfd'
```

Be careful with formatting. If column 'B' is integer you should put 2 instead of '2' as a condition.

Comment: Can I use `df['A'].eq('A')` a variable in `eq()` instead of a value and what i should do?   For example: `col_var = "C"`, `df['A'].eq(col_var)`

Comment: Yes, you can use a variable and it will work.